Creating a plugin for worpdress(Woo) to integrate Stripe API on order complete and create a customer with default payment method attached
I'm trying to make my plugin to create a customer in Stripe dashboard and create and after attach payment method that customer was using during checkout. Everything is good until I'm trying to create a payment method, because no payment ID is generated, only paymentIntents. I'm using WooCommerce Stripe Gateway to connect Stripe.
function capture_payment_method_id( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    if ( ! $order ) {
        error_log( 'Order not found for ID: ' . $order_id );
        return;
    }

    // Retrieve Payment Intent ID from order meta
    $payment_intent_id = $order->get_meta( '_stripe_intent_id' );

    if ( ! $payment_intent_id ) {
        error_log( 'No Payment Intent ID found for Order ID: ' . $order_id );
        return;
    }

    $stripe_secret_key = 'sk_test_'; 
    $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient( $stripe_secret_key );

    try {
        // Retrieve Payment Intent from Stripe
        $payment_intent = $stripe->paymentIntents->retrieve( $payment_intent_id );

        // Extract Payment Method ID
        if ( isset( $payment_intent->payment_method ) ) {
            $payment_method_id = $payment_intent->payment_method;

            // Save Payment Method ID in order meta
            $order->update_meta_data( '_stripe_payment_method_id', $payment_method_id );
            $order->save();

            error_log( 'Payment Method ID saved: ' . $payment_method_id );
        } else {
            error_log( 'Payment Method ID not found in Payment Intent.' );
        }
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        error_log( 'Error retrieving Payment Intent: ' . $e->getMessage() );
    }
}

What I get that there is no that payment ID in order meta, however the plugin should handle this, even card is saved on the site for future use, so my guess is that the ID is somewhere, and I'm not fetching this correctly. Also, I can't get card details directly due to the restrictions etc.
Is it possible to get the payment ID from order meta or something?

Are you also creating these PaymentIntents or are these being created by WooCommerce? The reason I ask is because attaching a PaymentMethod to a Customer should be done as part of the PaymentIntent. What you should do instead is create a Customer, create a PaymentIntent for that specific Customer and include setup_future_usage: 'off_session' if you intend to use that PaymentMethod for future off_session payments. When you confirm the PaymentIntent client side with the PaymentElement, the PaymentMethod that is created as part of that action will be automatically attached to the Customer.
